# Eclipse j2ee and bundled web tool platform confuses me

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, seam

Hello good fellas i'm sure everybody is cool.I'm about to start a tutorial about jsp and jsf and the required tool is eclipse for j2ee and web tool platform.I'm a bit confused about where to find it bundled with wtp? and in which distribution is it [Europa](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/europa/winter) ,  [Galileo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/R/eclipse-jee-galileo-win32.zip) or [Ganymede](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/ganymede/SR2/eclipse-jee-ganymede-SR2-win32.zip) ?.i know that it's here in 
[entreprise java](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=enterprise) because it's clearly written there but then i don't know whether it's good for me, the main idea being to add jboss-tools to in order to use jboss seam.Please correct me right away if i'm making some foolish assumptions.thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Galileo, its the latest. To me they chose names, instead of or along with versions, to make it easy to choose and remember, but apparently made it much difficult to choose.

See this, [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases), for clarification on releases.

Comment: I was a bit confused. Is Galileo finished and not in beta/RC any more?

Comment: No its out of beta now. Its safe to go for that.

Comment: Check this out, to be sure. http://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20090624_galileo.php

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse downloads you mentioned are all good candidates. I use the Ganymede (3.4) version but plan to try Galileo (3.5) soon as it is finished now (thanks *@Vinegar*).

I have also good experience with the non-free MyEclipse and I'm sure, Netbeans and Intellij have similarly good support for J2EE along with potential JBoss/Seam support.

You could test your installment by creating a JSP and check if you get syntax highlight for HTML and java snipplets.

Comment: Netbeans doesn't have it, unfortunately. Otherwise I would have already suggested that to the original poster. Actually, I myself practiced Seam on eclipse, just because there is no Jboss-Seam plugin for Netbeans yet.

Comment: Thank you. This is why I wrote 'potential' as I'm not familiar with all aspects of NetBeans.

Comment: So bottom line i go for the galileo distribution and the wtp is bundled with the j2ee version of eclipse.I use netbeans for php and j2se and waiting for new features.currently using the version 6.5.1.thanks to you all